# Imageboard-like forum system available for public usage?

Tags: forum, communication, self-hosted

Is there any imageboard-like forum software?

I mean something like imageboard, but with users and forum features (like PMs, reputation and stuff).

If you could imagine something like Facebook with some text formatting (BBCode is preferred, but Markdown and others will go) and other basic imageboard features as self-hostable software, it would be something I'm looking for.

I don't care about its system requirements, I have a good webhotel in trusted hosting company, and if it doesn't run here, I can host it in my own physical server.

Comment: "other basic imageboard features": Which would that be? Is BBCode required, or could a different syntax be used? What exactly do you mean with "licensed as publicly available"? --- Do you want to self-host the software? If yes, any server restrictions?

Comment: I think that any text formatting will go (like Markdown, BBCode, WYSIWYG etc.). And yes, it is required to be self-hostable. I don't care about server restrictions, I have a paid good webhotel for this purpose, and as a last resort I can host it myself in my own physical server. Thank for your comment, I'll update my question.